# map function with multiple arguments to each row of Array in Julia

Tags: function, julia, apply

In an attempt to simplify my code in Julia, I have the following command:

```
L=rand(50,50)
function f(l)
  n=mapslices(function g(x) partialsortperm(x,1:l,rev=true) end,L,dims=2)
  return n
end
map(f,[34; 24 ;17])
```

This command is supposed to apply the function `g` to each row of the Array `L`, where at each time, the function is applied with 3 different values of the argument `l`. I attempted to create a unique function, to eliminate the function inside a function:

```
 function f(A::Array,l::Int64)
     partialsortperm(A,1:l,rev=true)
 end
```

and tried to use `map(f,eachrow(L),[34; 24; 17])` but not getting what I want, because the function `f` has now 2 arguments and I don't know how to use 2 arguments with `map` or `mapslices`.

Comment: You can define an anonymous function that accepts two arguments like this: `(x, y) -> f(x, y)`. This could serve as the first argument to `map`.

Comment: Passing this `(x, y) -> f(x, y)` would be equivalent of passing `f`, no need to construct an extra function. Maybe you mean `x->f(x,y)` to create a closure?

Comment: The point was to illustrate how you can specify an anonymous function with two input arguments. In this case, it would be something along the lines of `(A, n)->partialsortperm(A, 1:n, rev=true)`.

Comment: @coolsv - in this case you cannot use a flat `map`, as `map` assumes that all collections you iterate over have the same length (as is not the case in your example). Therefore you need to nest iteration over rows of `L` and have an outer `map` over the `[30,24,17]` vector. Actually you could even write `f.([34,24,17])`. However - as noted above, you can shorten the definition of `f` to simply `f(l) = mapslices(x -> partialsortperm(x,1:l,rev=true), L, dims=2)`

Comment: Thank you for your precious help from all of you :-)